# get data within html ellements using beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have done this so far:

```
import urllib2,re,time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url="http://nairobinow.wordpress.com/"
rawEventsData=urllib2.urlopen(base_url).read()
rawEventssoup = BeautifulSoup(rawEventsData)
events=rawEventssoup.findAll("div", {"id": re.compile(r'post-[\d+]')})
```

now I would like to get the data after the  tag,the venue and the date.This is the events block(just one of the iterated sections):

```
<div class="post-17149 post type" id="post-17149">
<h2><a href="http://nairobinow.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/out/">Out of Town: Lamuest</a> 
</h2><p>u
Dates: November 15-18, 2012<br/>
Venue: Lamu</p>
<p>Accommodation information: <a href="http://.../index.html"target="_blank"  
>http://www.lamu.org/index.html</a></p></div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you're interested in the data within the `<p>` tags. If that is correct...

If you're not already aware, `.findAll()` returns a list. In this case, any `div` with the corresponding `id` will be returned.

All you need to do is iterate over `events`:

```
for event in events:
    print event('p')[0]
```

This will return:

```
<p>u Dates: November 15-18, 2012<br/> Venue: Lamu</p>
```

Use `.contents` to remove tags. Please note that `.contents` will call the text based on its index. ie: `.contents[0]` will probably return `Dates: November 15-18,` whereas `.contents[1]` will probably return `Venue: Lamu`.

You should play around with this and find what suits your needs. I hope this answered the question, it was a bit vague, but though I'd give it a shot anyway.

Comment: Hi,I tried this,and its been really helpful,except am still getting tags(a tags) when I use .contents.I would like to retrieve the contents in the h2 tags too.I would like the output to be:Out of Town: Lamuest;Dates: November 15-18, 2012;Venue: Lamu;

Comment: Apply the same pattern. If the `<a>` is within the `<p>`, simply add `('a')[0]` and so on. The full line: `print event('p')[0]('a')[0].contents[0]` <-- just one example.

Comment: I had to re-read your question. For the `<h2>` tags, `print event('h2')[0]('a')[0].contents[0]` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot,this has really saved me a great deal of time and effort.